# Perl grep start of pattern to END of pattern

Tags: perl, grep, matching

Hi I have file example as below . Using perl i require to grep lines from Feature A - Feature B

```
FeatureA:Y
Suporrted devices
:
:
:
:Suported device
FeatureB:Y
Suporrted devices
:
:
:
:Suported device
FeatureC:Y
:
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly? What have you tried so far? What does not work?

Comment: I have feature feature name ex FeatureA  i need to find devices supported under feature i tried @arg1 = grep ( /$txt/i ,@arg); it only matches the feature not the entire list

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne'print if /^FeatureA:/ .. /^FeatureB:/'
```

...Then again, you probably only want lines *up to* the FeatureB line, so

```
perl -ne'print if ( /^FeatureA:/ .. /^FeatureB:/ ) =~ /^\d+\z/;'
```

Comment: `/E0/` might be shorter regex? and personal question, why do you prefer `\z`?

Comment: @mpapec, That would only print the FeatureB line, or all lines except FeatureB line if you negate it.

Comment: @mpapec, As opposed to what? `$`? Why would I want to check for a newline?

Comment: I've meant `!~ /E0/`. `\z` and `$` should behave identical here as there is no newline for `..` operator?

Comment: @mpapec, Like I said, that would print all lines except FeatureB, which is very wrong. // Yes, and so would `\n?\z`. Should I use that?

Comment: use what you want but `$` and `\z` doesn't differ in this particular case, and `$` is shorter. `!~ /E0/` does same thing as `=~ /^\d+\z/` for above code